# Is there a way to edit views fields in place?

Tags: 7, views

I haven't tried the [Editview](http://drupal.org/project/editview) or [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) modules for Drupal 6, but neither is available yet for Drupal 7 anyway.

I'd like to provide a way for my users to edit lots of nodes and node fields on one screen, presented preferably to views. I'd rather they don't have to keep following a link (contextual or otherwise) to another edit form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [editablefields-d7](http://drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1130436); as reported by the project page the module is a Drupal 7 port of editable fields.
The project is a sandbox project, which means it doesn't support releases, yet, and drupal.org doesn't automatically create the archive containing the module code; this means the code should be considered experimental, and you get the code using git, using `git clone http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1130436.git editablefields_d7` or the link to the [snapshot archive](http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/damz/1130436.git/snapshot/refs/heads/7.x.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks - I'll be watching that space. I tried it out and couldn't get it to work, but it's a sandbox, of course, and makes no claims of stability or anything else. Thanks for doing that DamZ!

Comment: Yay, so there are some restrictions, but it does work. It's a formatter, so you have to select a formatter (editable (HTML) or editable(AJAX). And the fact that it's a formatter means that it can't be used on titles. DamZ suggests that title module might work, but that it's in a bit of a raw state.

Comment: At this point it may be better to link directly to http://drupal.org/project/editablefields 

7.x-1.0-alpha1 is now available as a Recommended Release.

Answer (score 0):

The drupal community is working hard to make WYSYWYG edit-in-place functionality (using the Aloha project) be built into drupal 8 [read about spark initiative](http://buytaert.net/spark-update-in-line-editing-in-drupal). For the meanwhile, people are telling the spark D7 distribution should do it visually (I haven't tried it myself yet), as well as the modules above (non-WYSYWYG).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, there's a new module that's now a project that allows you to edit multiple fields at once:

https://drupal.org/project/editableviews

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited.
>   Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save'
>   button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.